# Animated transitions between VisualStates

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing Windows 8.1 application, the landing page is composed of list view for item selection in the left side and GridView with selected item details takes remaining space.

I also implemented VisualStates with logical navigation for snapped state. I have SnappedMain with GridView.Visibility set to collapsed and SnappedDetails with FlipView for displaying item details in vertical way, in this state almost all other elements' visibility set collapsed.

Now I need to implement transition fly-in animations between SnappedMain and SnappedDetails, but have no clue for this one, because only Visibility is changing in states. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Check out `VisualStateGroup.Transitions`

Comment: Can you provide a small XAML sample?